# Can't pass String to controller through ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, playframework

I'm new of web development with play framework and ajax,Now I want to pass the string in the form to controller with ajax but I don't know how to do.Could you please help me?Here is my code:
html:

```
<form onsubmit="return newSearch();" id="formId">
    <input type="search" placeholder="Search for more" id="searchBar_chat">
</form>
<script type="text/javascript" >
function newSearch()
{
    var s = document.getElementById("chatDialgue");
    var searchValue = document.getElementById("searchBar_chat").value;
    s.innerHTML = s.innerHTML + '<li>'+ searchValue +'</li>';
    document.getElementById("searchBar_chat").value ="";
    $.ajax({
        url: "DataMatch/searchContentMatch",  
        type:"GET",
        cache: false,
        dataType:"text",
        data:"searchValue",
        success: function (responseData) {  
        s.innerHTML = s.innerHTML + '<li>'+responseData+'</li>';  
        }  
        });
    return false;
}
</script>
```

controller:

```
public class DataMatch extends Controller{

  public String searchContentMatch (String search) {
    // Search match
    return "HI"+search;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, in the data parameter of `$.ajax()` you have to build a query string, so the correct way is concatenating the key ("search") with its value (searchValue).

Then, you don't need neither that `return false` statement in the script nor the `return` keyword on the `onsubmit` form attribute.

Lastly, since you're using jQuery, take advantage of its selection capabilities and replace `document.getElementById` with `$`.

```
<form onsubmit="newSearch();" id="formId">
    <input type="search" placeholder="Search for more" id="searchBar_chat">
</form>
<script type="text/javascript" >
function newSearch(){
    var searchValue = $("#searchBar_chat").val();
    $("#chatDialgue").append('<li>'+ searchValue +'</li>');
    $("#searchBar_chat").val("");
    $.ajax({
        url: "DataMatch/searchContentMatch",  
        type:"GET",
        cache: false,
        dataType: "text",
        data: "search=" + searchValue,
        success: function (responseData) {  
            $("#chatDialgue").append('<li>' + responseData + '</li>');
        }  
    });
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass it as a Query Parameter since it is just a single string.

```
var search="searchValue";
 $.ajax({
        url: "DataMatch/searchContentMatch?search="+search,  
        type:"GET",
        cache: false,
        dataType:"text",
        success: function (responseData) {  
        s.innerHTML = s.innerHTML + '<li>'+responseData+'</li>';  
        }  
        });
```

Comment: This way you pass a static string, while OP seemed to want to pass the value of the input form (although the code was wrong).

Comment: yeah. But if he wants, he can get the value from input and pass it as seen in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the [Javascript router](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaJavascriptRouting) instead of hardcoding the endpoint in your Javascript code. This will allow you to change the endpoint name later on if needed. Also, you want to pass a query string parameter, so it goes directly in the URL. Here is how to use the reverse route:

```
@helper.javascriptRouter("jsRoutes")(
    routes.javascript.DataMatch.searchContentMatch
)

//HTML here

var endpoint = jsRoutes.controllers.DataMatch.searchContentMatch(searchValue).url;
$.ajax({
  url: endpoint,  
  type:"GET",
  cache: false,
  success: function (responseData) {  
  s.innerHTML = s.innerHTML + '<li>'+responseData+'</li>';  
  }  
});
```

Answer (score 0):

One more thing, to the previous answer, do not forget about parameter in the routes file:

```
GET    /api/search/:search             controllers.DataMatch.searchContentMatch(search: String)
```